# How to plot a pandas dataframe with andrew_curves?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas, plot

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/file/file.csv',
                 header=0, sep=',', names=['PhraseId', 'SentenceId', 'Phrase', 'Sentiment'])
```

I would like to print it with [andrew_curves](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) i tried the following:

```
andrews_curves(df, 'Name')
```

Any idea of how to plot this?. This is the content of the csv:

```
PhraseId, SentenceId, Phrase, Sentiment
1, 1, A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story ., 1
2, 1, A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose, 2
3, 1, A series, 2
4, 1, A, 2
5, 1, series, 2
6, 1, of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose, 2
7, 1, of, 2
8, 1, escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose, 2
9, 1, escapades, 2
10, 1, demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose, 2
11, 1, demonstrating the adage, 2
12, 1, demonstrating, 2
13, 1, the adage, 2
14, 1, the, 2
15, 1, adage, 2
16, 1, that what is good for the goose, 2
17, 1, that, 2
18, 1, what is good for the goose, 2
19, 1, what, 2
20, 1, is good for the goose, 2
21, 1, is, 2
22, 1, good for the goose, 3
23, 1, good, 3
24, 1, for the goose, 2
25, 1, for, 2
26, 1, the goose, 2
27, 1, goose, 2
28, 1, is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story ., 2
29, 1, is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story, 2
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried? Did it give an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [the doc page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) that you linked to, the Iris dataset has a column called `'Name'`. When you call

```
andrews_curves(data, 'Name')
```

the rows of `data` are grouped by the value of `Name`. That's why for the Iris
dataset you get three different colors for the lines.

In your dataset you have three columns: `A`, `B`, `C`. To call `andrews_curves` on your `df`, you first need to identify the value you want to group by. If, for example, it is the value of the `C` column, then call

```
andrews_curves(data, 'C')
```

If, on the other hand, you want to group *by the column names*, `A`, `B`, `C`, then 
first melt your DataFrame to convert it from wide format to long format, and
then call `andrews_curves` on the `variable` column (which holds the value
`A`,`B`, or `C` for each row):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.plotting as pdplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.sin(x**2)/x,
                   'B': np.sin(x)*np.exp(-x),
                   'C': np.cos(x)*x})
pdplt.andrews_curves(pd.melt(df), 'variable')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: This is too abstract. I don't know what "switching the key" means. Please post a sample of `text.csv` and the code you are running which raises the TypeError.

Comment: Thanks for your help @unutbu. I updated the question, I would like to plot the andrews curves given that little intance data.

Comment: @skwoi: The `andrews_curves` function expects all columns of the dataframe to be numerical. You'll probably want to convert the `Phrase` column into numbers of some sort. It's not obvious to me how you're going to do that. The other problem is that you need to specify a column to group by. There is no obvious candidate in your data.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. For this type of data what other kind of plot do you recommend me?.